# How to only allow the numbers ,backspace key and hypen key to be pressed on textbox

Tags: c#, maskedtextbox

I made a textbox to to insert a phone number . I only want numbers, delete button and hyphen key to be pressed. 
I used following code :
It works for delete button and numbers , what shoud I do for hyphen?

```
private void ContactNumTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    const char Hyphen = (char)2d;
    const char Delete = (char)8;
    if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != Hyphen && e.KeyChar!= Delete)
        e.Handled = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using hex numbers, you must prefix the number with `0x`. Your code currently compiles due to the coincidence that `d` specifies the number is a double. The following code will correctly detect hyphens:

```
private void ContactNumTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    const char hyphen = (char)0x2D;
    const char delete = (char)0x08;
    if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != hyphen && e.KeyChar!= delete)
        e.Handled = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this one

```
if (!(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back || e.KeyChar == '-'))
{
     e.Handled = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write this code in KeyPress event:

```
    private void txtTextBoxName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != 8;
    }
```